# Accessing the images folder in wpf app

Tags: wpf, path

I have a wpf application in which I want to save a file in the Images folder, which is on the same level with the bin folder.

How do I access that folder?

I try like this:

```
using (var imageFile = new FileStream((new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/Application/")).ToString(), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    //
                }
```

and I get the error that "The given path's format is not supported.". How can I access that folder?

Answer (score 0):

Your path refers to resources within the project assembly. You should use relative or absolute file system paths:

```
var path = Path.Combine(
    Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), 
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 
    "Images"); // Result could be for example: "C:\MyWorkspace\MyProject\bin\Debug\Images"

using (var imageFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)) { }
```

Comment: I said that the Images folder is on the same level as the bin folder, not inside the bin\Debug.

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` returns your application base directory, where your executable is running from. Use double dots (`@"..\Images"`) to direct to parent directories. Why would you place the images into the bin folder anyways?

Answer (score 0):

How about using double dots(..) to get to parent directory.

using (var imageFile = new FileStream("..\..\[Path goes here]", FileMode.Create))
            {
                //
            }